# DSolve returning InverseFunction while I believe the answer isn't so complicated

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, inverse-function

I was trying to solve the following differential equation: 
$$A'(y)^2 =  -\frac{1}{l^2} e^{-2A(y)} + \frac{1}{L^2}.$$
I know that one possible answer is
$$A(y) = \log\left( \frac{L}{l}\cosh\frac{y}{L}\right),$$
which isn't too complicated.  There is a more general answer (with some free parameter that needed to be fixed to a certain value to obtain the solution above) that I don't know but I've seen it and I know it's not too complicated either.

Still, when I try to solve it using

```
DSolve[(A'[y])^2 == -1/(l^2) Exp[-2*A[y]] + 1/(L^2), A[y], y]
```

*Mathematica* returns

```
{{A[y] ->  InverseFunction[( E^#1 Sqrt[l^2 - E^(-2 #1) L^2]
Log[l (E^#1 l + Sqrt[E^(2 #1) l^2 - L^2])])/( l Sqrt[E^(2 #1) l^2 - L^2]) &]
[-(y/(l L)) + C[1]]},
{A[y] ->  InverseFunction[(E^#1 Sqrt[l^2 - E^(-2 #1) L^2]
Log[l (E^#1 l + Sqrt[E^(2 #1) l^2 - L^2])])/(l Sqrt[E^(2 #1) l^2 - L^2]) &]
[y/(l L) + C[1]]}}
```

Why can't I get a nicer output?  I'm pretty sure there is a way to make it nicer, so I must be doing something wrong (I'm completely new to *Mathematica*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a bit of assistance, `DSolve` can obtain a simpler general answer.  Begin by changing dependent variables

```
Unevaluated[(D[a[y], y]^2 + 1/(l^2) Exp[-2*a[y]] - 1/(L^2))] /. a[y] -> Log[b[y]];
eq = Simplify[% b[y]^2]
(* 1/l^2 - b[y]^2/L^2 + Derivative[1][b][y]^2 *)
```

Then solve this equation

```
DSolve[eq == 0, b[y], y] // Expand
(* {{b[y] -> E^(y/L + l C[1])/(2 l^2) + 1/2 E^(-(y/L) - l C[1]) L^2}, 
    {b[y] -> E^(-(y/L) + l C[1])/(2 l^2) + 1/2 E^(y/L - l C[1]) L^2}} *)
```

redefine the constant of integration

```
FullSimplify[% /. l C[1] -> c + Log[l L]] // Flatten
(* {b[y] -> (L Cosh[c + y/L])/l}, {b[y] -> (L Cosh[c - y/L])/l} *)
```

and transform back to the original variable `a[y]`

```
Rule[a[y], Log[#[[2]]]] & /@ %
(* {a[y] -> Log[(L Cosh[c + y/L])/l], a[y] -> Log[(L Cosh[c - y/L])/l]} *)
```

which is the desired general result.

**Simplification**

Actually, the two solutions are the same, as can be seen by replacing `c` by `-c` in the second solution.

Comment: Am I missing something or are these steps really not so obvious? How does one see that these are the necessary steps to be taken to solve the problem? Is there some general rule to be followed?

Comment: @user138784  At first, I tried to convert the original `DSolve` answer to a simpler form but with only partial success.  Then, I decide to try changing dependent variables, which is a common course of action, and I chose `Log` to eliminate `Exp` from the ODE.  I used the substitution `l C[1] -> c + Log[l L]` to cast the exponentials into a form in which they could be converted into hyperbolic functions.  These were the key steps.

Comment: Thanks but I was wondering if there was a general rule to be followed to solve this kind of problems or if this was just done by rewriting it with trial and error until Mathematica figured out how to solve it.

Comment: @user138784  Not that I am aware of.  However, for first order ODEs in which the independent variable does not appear explicitly, `Integrate` also can be used.