# Solve an equation for different values

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, boundary-conditions

I was trying to solve this equation for different value of a constant (a) but the solution is not different for those values?!! b and m are positive values.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqns = {(y'[t]/ y[t])^2 == b / y[t]^(3m) + a/3};
Simplify[DSolve[eqns, y[t], t], Assumptions -> {a > 0}]
Simplify[DSolve[eqns, y[t], t], Assumptions -> {a < 0}]
```

Comment: Why do you think it is not working? You clearly do get a solution, but Mathematica just cannot express it explicitly so it is written as a ``InverseFunction``. If there exists an explicit solution, you will probably need to do some manual transformations – see for example [DSolve returning InverseFunction while I believe the answer isn't so complicated](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101551/dsolve-returning-inversefunction-while-i-believe-the-answer-isnt-so-complicated).

Comment: I'm sorry, you'r right but I want to know the manual transformations

Comment: Then please change the title and the content of your question accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to solve the inverse problem

```
eqns = {(y'[t]/y[t])^2 == b/y[t]^(3 m) + a/3} 
solys = Solve[eqns, y'[t]]

odes = Map[t'[y] == 1/y'[t] /. # /. y[t] -> y &, solys](* ode in t[y]:
{Derivative[1][t][y] == -(Sqrt[3]/Sqrt[a y^2 + 3 b y^(2 - 3 m)   ]), 
Derivative[1][t][y] == Sqrt[3]/Sqrt[a y^2 + 3 b y^(2 - 3 m)]} *)


DSolve[odes[[1]], t, y]
(* {{t -> Function[{y}, -((2 y Sqrt[a + 3 b y^(-3 m)]ArcTanh[Sqrt[a + 3 b y^(-3 m)]/Sqrt[a]])/(Sqrt[3] Sqrt[a] m Sqrt[y^2 (a + 3 b y^(-3 m))])) + C[1]]}}*)

DSolve[odes[[2]], t, y]
(*{{t -> Function[{y}, (2 y Sqrt[a + 3 b y^(-3 m)]ArcTanh[Sqrt[a + 3 b y^(-3 m)]/Sqrt[a]])/(Sqrt[3] Sqrt[a] m Sqrt[y^2 (a + 3 b y^(-3 m))]) + C[1]]}}*)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is a good idea but I'm working on some condition that my solution will be Sin [] and Sinh[] !

Comment: Like this Clear["Global`*"]
eqns = {(y'[t]/ y[t]) == Sqrt[b/ y[t]^(3m) + a/3]};
Simplify[DSolve[eqns, y[t], t], 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, m > 1}]